# ¿Que flujo o consideraciones sigue la revisión de un reporte?

Tags: soporte, reportes

Hago esta pregunta con el fin de tener una idea clara respecto a la publicación 
[LogFile' object has no attribute 'isatty](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152999/logfile-object-has-no-attribute-isatty) la cual inicialmente estaba hecha en ingles y decidí hacer un reporte del tipo **no relacionado** ya que hay muchas preguntas del mismo tipo en la cual el usuario no se da cuenta por distracción o cualquier otra razón que  realiza la pregunta escrita en ese idioma.

Revisando hoy día mi cuenta me aparece un mensaje en la parte baje del modal de reportes que mi ultimo reporte fue rechazado **hace 9 horas** tomando  la hora que hago esta publicación.

Me puse a revisar la pregunta y veo que esta fue traducida aproximadamente  **4 horas después** de ser publicada. Y por ello me vino la duda de que se rechazo mi reporte porque la pregunta ya fue editada , pero el reporte fue hecho en un lapso en el cual estaba en ingles.

Agradezco el tiempo que se tomen en leer mi  pregunta y quisiera saber como dato adicional si se puede borrar o cancelar un reporte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Flujo**

Un reporte de cierre envía a la pregunta a la cola de cierre para que otros miembros de la comunidad la revisen ([3000+](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)).

Si al menos uno de los votos de los revisores es "Cerrar", tu reporte es marcado como **útil**.

Si 3 revisores deciden "Dejar abierta", tu reporte es **rechazado.**

Un moderador ♦ podría evaluar tu reporte directamente, y la decisión de éste sería el resultado directo en tu reporte. No obstante, lo más normal es que la propia comunidad gestione los cierres.

Si ves que la pregunta fue editada, y que tu reporte deja de ser válido, podrías ir nuevamente a `reportar`, y seleccionar **`Retractar`**.

**Tu caso**

Hiciste muy bien en reportar. Está perfecto que lo hayas hecho en una publicación en inglés. Normalmente un revisor lo evalúa y vota para cerrar casi inmediatamente. Sin embargo, en este caso se evaluó en:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/91100

luego de que la tradujera. Por ese motivo los 3 revisores votaron para dejar abierta.

En definitiva, **no hay nada de lo que tengas que preocuparte en este caso**.

Comment: Añadir que esta es otra manifestación del problema de revisión que tenemos. La pregunta debió cerrarse casi inmediatamente, pero tardamos demasiado en revisar las colas. En este caso no es importante, ya que la pregunta de todas maneras sería reabierta al ser traducida, pero es un indicativo mas.